# Where is GuiceApplicationBuilder?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I am currently trying to set up a Play2 application with dependency injection, with information from [the official docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection). However, my IDE cannot find `GuiceApplicationBuilder`. So which additional entry for `libraryDependencies` do I have to specify to get this builder?

EDIT: I made a screenshot of what happens when I try to import the things stated by @anquegi

[image: Nonexisting dependencies]

EDIT 2: The problem was very simple: I used the wrong version of Play - 2.3.8 did in fact not have these, I had to use 2.4.0-RC2 to get it to work.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder

Comment: I found this page, too, but it does not tell me what dependencies I have to add.

Comment: It sounds like your dependencies are not being properly managed. What are you using to manage them? Maven? Gradle? Something else? IDEA built-in? Please answer by [edit]ing your post, not by commenting.

Comment: are you sure that class exists? [Central shows nothing by that class name!](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7CGuiceApplicationBuilder)

Answer (score 1):

At the dependencies in the play docs [/ScalaDependencyInjection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) you must import this

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.inject._
import play.api.inject.guice._
```

This is the compile code in the section Advanced: Extending the `GuiceApplicationLoader`, so you need to use this extending in your class:

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.inject._
import play.api.inject.guice._

class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader() {
  override def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
    val extra = Configuration("a" -> 1)
    initialBuilder
      .in(context.environment)
      .loadConfig(extra ++ context.initialConfiguration)
      .overrides(overrides(context): _*)
  }
}
```